# Is it possible to use a .NET Framework 4.7+ assembly with MSI as Embedded UI?

Tags: .net, wpf, wix, windows-installer

I'm building a Windows app and using MSI (via WIX and Wix#) for my installer.

I have built a WPF based Embedded UI that is invoked instead of the standard MSI UI.

It all works fine as long as I stick to .NET Framework 3.5 or below capabilities. But if I upgrade my project to use anything > than 3.5 I get errors like this:

[image]

Is it even possible to use a .NET Framework 4.7+ assembly with MSI as Embedded UI? If so, how do I configure my project correctly to do so?

Note that the primary reason I want to use a newer version (beyond being able to leverage nice stuff in later versions) is making the UI look correct on Windows 10. Right now, my UI has a Windows 7 look:

[image]

I may be barking up the wrong tree here, and there may be a way to force my .NET 3.5-based WPF assembly do the right thing relative to visual styles in Windows 10, similar to how it can be done in WinForms like this:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Here's how to make it work.

First, you need a `.config` file for WIX# to consume that specifies the `supportedRuntime` and sets `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"`.

`CustomAction.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" >
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Second, in your Wix# app (e.g. `setup.cs`) use `WixProject.CAConfigFile` to point to this `.config` file:

```cs
     project.CAConfigFile = "CustomAction.config";
     project.BuildMsi();
```

Note, you should consider carefully what .NET Framework to require for your WIX Embedded UI. For example, Windows 10 is guaranteed to have at least .NET Framework 4.6. If you specify something greater than that, you will either need to install it as part of your installer or have your users do so.

Ta-da:
[image]